# C# Nhibernate ConnectionProvider.cs cannot be found

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to setup Nhibernate with an oracle database so far i have the following:

**App.config (ive commented out the username and password for protection)**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
      <property name="query.substitutions">hqlFunction=SQLFUNC</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=CTIR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****;Unicode=True</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <mapping assembly="TestNhibernate" />
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

**Agenter.cs**:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestNhibernate
{
    class Agenter
    {
        public virtual int ID {get; set;}
        public virtual String Initialer { get; set; }
        public virtual String Fornavn { get; set; }
        public virtual String efternavn { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**AGENTER_LISTE.hbm.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TestNhibernate" namespace="TestNhibernate">
  <class name="Agenter">
    <id name="ID" column="ID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Initialer" />
    <property name="Fornavn" />
    <property name="Efternavn" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Form1.cs:**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate;

namespace TestNhibernate
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Configuration myConfig;
        private ISessionFactory mySessionFactory;
        private ISession mySession;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myConfig = new Configuration();
            myConfig.Configure();
            mySessionFactory = myConfig.BuildSessionFactory(); <--- this is where it goes wrong
            mySession = mySessionFactory.OpenSession();

            using (mySession.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Agenter agent = new Agenter {Fornavn = "Marc", Initialer = "MRCR212", ID = 999, efternavn = "Rasmussen" };
                mySession.Save(agent);
                mySession.Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i get the following error:

```
Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver.
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle now allows for an XCopy deployment.

But you gotta do some legwork.

http://dbaportal.eu/2013/02/22/true-xcopy-runtime-for-oracle-odp-net-application/

Comment: It simply means that you can just include a few files..and make Oracle run.  "back in the day", you had to run a full oracle-client installer.  and sometimes alter the .tns entries.  Now...you can simply include a few files..and use a connection-string....that points to the server/port# etc.  "back in the day", you'd point to a tns entry.

Comment: Here is a simpler version of the idea : http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/connect-to-an-oracle-database-without-an-oracle-client.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **Oracle.DataAcess.dll** is in the GAC or in your bin folder.

Comment: Where can the dll file be found?

Comment: You probably need to download the ODP package https://community.oracle.com/thread/2511652?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Oracle released Managed drivers and they work well with nhibernate I would use them instead of Oracle.DataAccess.dll. They are far less in size and your binaries can be any cpu